# Update Elasticsearch index from Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-painless

I want to update documents in an Elasticsearch index from PySpark. The update should not change all fields, but only change/add some fields of the document. The number of documents is very large. The data is stored in a Spark dataframe.

I was able to update a specific field in the documents using a painless script.

```
es_conf {
  "es.update.script.inline": "ctx._source['field'] = params['index']"
}

dataframe.write.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql')\
        .options(**es_conf)\
        .save(("index"), mode = 'append')
```

However, there are millions of fields to be updated and the params are stored as a string, so I think this won't work out.

It would be perfect if I could access the "local" dataframe fields containing the data for the update. Something like:

```
"es.update.script.inline": "ctx._source['field'] = ctx._source['new_data']"
```

where the field new_data is read from the local Spark dataframe. Is this somehow possible?

Alternatively, could I create a second ES index with all the data and then update my index from there?